# Spring Security-Spring Cloud Gateway

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices, spring-cloud-gateway

I want to implement OAuth2 with JWKS in a Microservice A with Container Tomcat and use it as a resource server in Microservice B, where Microservice B is a Spring Cloud Gateway with Container Netty. For more details, Microservice B is an API gateway and I want to check tokens with the private and public keys that I implemented in Microservice A. I want to use Microservice A as an OAuth2 resource server in Microservice B, but the problem is that Microservice A has Container Tomcat for blocking programming and Microservice B has Container Netty for non-blocking programming.

How can Configure Security Settings in Microservice B for use Outh2 Resource Server of Microservice A.

[in this picture i write security config in Microservice "Chat" That Check Tokens with Outh2ResoruceServer method that i Highlighted in picture. I want check this preducre in Microservice B Or Microservice Api Gateway. i don't want check token that is valid or not in Microservice Chat. I want Check Token with Outh2ResourceServer in Microservice B or Microservice Api gateway.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jeScT.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.